# NDSolve::derlen: The length of the derivative operator Derivative[1,2] in (y^(1,2))[x,z] is not the same as the number of arguments

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

This is a part of my code, where this error is showing. What is the mistake?

```
(*Define the PDE*)
eq = D[(e[v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14,
      v15, v16, v17][x, z]*inertia*D[y[x, z], {x, 2}] + 
  e[v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, 
     v15, v16, v17][x, z]*inertia*D[y[x, z], {z, 2}]), {x, 
 2}] == -w[x];

(*Define the boundary conditions for PDE*)
bcs = {Derivative[1, 0][y][0, z] == 0,(*y'[0,z]==0*)
   Derivative[1, 0][y][l, z] == 0,(*y'[l,z]==0*)
   Derivative[0, 1][y][x, -h/2] == 0,(*y[x,-h/2]==0*)
   Derivative[0, 1][y][x, h/2] == 0};  (*y[x,h/2]==0*)

(*Use NDSolve with boundary conditions*)
sol = NDSolve[{eq, bcs}, y, {x, 0, l}, {z, -h/2, h/2}, vd, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> es}}];
```

Comment: Function `e[...]`is undefined!

Comment: `vd` is not defined. Please include the smallest amount so that others can scrape your code off the screen, paste it into an empty new notebook, run it and see the error that you see.

Comment: Here I have provided a small part of my code. e[...] and vd are defined in my full code. but the error message i guess is related to length of derivative and arguments mismatch. can you see the equations and BCs where the mismatch is? @UlrichNeumann